# Change background of div based on value of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to get this javascript to read the value of the div "flow-hold" and change the background color based on the value.

I have a div named flow hold with a value of 132 for example, that I would like to see green because it is less than the 200 threshold. If the value exceeds the threshold, I would like it to be red.

```
<div class="flow-hold">132</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.flow-hold'), function(){
   if($(this).val()>=200){

       $('.flow-hold').css({"background-color":"red"});
   } else {
       $('.flow-hold').css({"background-color":"green"});

   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: How is the value of "flow-hold" being changed?  If it's coming from the server this way, just assign a class to it that gives the desired background color.

Comment: Your JavaScript is invalid, it has unbalanced `()` parenthesis. Error is around `, function()`. Did you intend to write `.each(function()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this simple and easy:

```
$('.flow-hold').each(function() {
   if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 200) {
      $(this).css("background-color","red");
    } else {
         $(this).css("background-color","green");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on page load you could use your Back-End technology to assign a CSS class with demanded color according to the threshold.

For example, in PHP it would be:

```
<div class="flow-hold <?=($threshold>=200)?'bg-red':'bg-green'?>">132</div>
```

In your CSS file:

```
bg-red{
background-color: red;
}
bg-green:{
background-color: green;
}
```

However, if you want to do it on client-side, you have to allocate an exact action to it, for instance:

```
<div class="flow-hold">132</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.flow-hold').on('hover', function(){
   if($(this).val()>=200){

       $('.flow-hold').css({"background-color":"red"});
   } else {
       $('.flow-hold').css({"background-color":"green"});

   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually your problem are the accessors that you are using. check that if you use `JQuery` and get the items by class you will get an `array` with all the divs containing that `class`.

so here you have a working example of what you wanted to achieve taking into account what I told before.

**NOTE:** your code doesn't run by itself, next time please fix it.
**NOTE2:** note that I didn't do a lot of changes and it started to work.

```js
function changeBackground() {
  let div = $('.flow-hold')[0];
  if (div.innerText >= 200) {
    $('.flow-hold').css({
      "background-color": "red"
    });
  } else {
    $('.flow-hold').css({
      "background-color": "green"
    });
  }

}

changeBackground();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flow-hold">132</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you intended to use the [`.each( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/each/#each1) jQuery method, where the function should only handle one element at a time, so it shouldn't lookup `$('.flow-hold')` again, since there can be more than one element with that class.

You should also use the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text1) method, not the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1) method.

```
$('.flow-hold').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() >= 200) {
        $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
    } else {
        $(this).css({"background-color":"green"});
    }
});
```

Since you are setting the same property in both cases, you can also use the implicit looping of the [`.css( propertyName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) method:

```
$('.flow-hold').css("background-color", function() {
    return ($(this).text() >= 200 ? "red" : "green");
});
```

Comment: @Philip Are you *really* asking how to write an `else if`? Or chaining ternary operators? *Really?!?* --- `txt < 100 ? "green" : txt < 200 ? "yellow" : "red"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var value = parseInt($('.flow-hold').html());

  if(value >= 200){
     $('.flow-hold').css("background-color","red");
  }
  else {
     $('.flow-hold').css("background-color","green");
  }
});
```